# How to integrate webflow code with angular web app?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, spring-webflow

I'm new in web development with angular, so I have the source code of a website developed with angular, and I want to personnalize and adapt this site  to my needs: My problem is: when I added a generated code from webflow to an existant partial page, the browser does not interprete my angular variables. I think that the problem is related to how I must import jquery and web flow js file.

In my partial page I integrated these lignes :

```
     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/webflow.14ca90e5b.js"></script>
```

Comment: Don't... try to avoid mixing angular and webflow. Trust me i've done it, it is horrendous.

Comment: @steves please what's the alternativ?

Comment: We wrote a series of REST endpoints which sit on top of webflow that way the pages load outside of webflow but the angular variable etc are populated by the REST responses.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue where webflow.js was not loading with angularjs. I managed to solve the issue following the solution suggested at below:

http://forum.webflow.com/t/use-of-web-app-frameworks-like-angular/3191/10

> Just a quick follow up letting folks know that my solution was to late
>   load the webflow library from Angular using this handy module created
>   by GitHib user @endorma.
>
> Here it is:
>   gist.github.com/endorama/736900690

Followed below steps in my codebase:

1. Download this Angular Module (https://gist.github.com/endorama/7369006) to load the webflowjs in lazy mode (i.e. once angularJS load has finished, then this module will get the webflowjs)
2. Import this module in AngularJS application dependencies
3. Download the webflow js and had to minify it and keep it at root of app (not in the app folder as it was conflicting with gulp load process)
4. Import the webflowjs in partial like <script type="text/javascript-lazy" src="webflow.min.js">

Hopefully it will help.

Thanks,
Gourav.